# Testing Shopware Login with Behat Mink

Tags: php, testing, behat, mink, shopware

I cannot seem to figure this one out.

I defined the following feature:

```
Feature: Login

  Scenario: Test Basic Login
    Given I am on "/account"
    And I login successfully as "demo@demo.de" with password "demodemo"
    Then I should see "Abmelden"
```

The feature context looks the following:

```
/**
 * @Given I login successfully as :arg1 with password :arg2
 */
public function iLoginSuccessfullyAsWithPassword($arg1, $arg2)
{
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $page->fillField('email', $arg1);
    $page->fillField('password', $arg2);
    $page->pressButton('Anmelden');
}
```

And to give a complete picture here my  behat.yml:

```
default:
  extensions:
  Behat\MinkExtension:
    base_url: "http://192.168.33.10/s5224"
    default_session: 'goutte'
    javascript_session: 'selenium2'
    goutte: ~
    selenium2: ~
```

Now The scenario runs well until `I should see "Abmelden"`. Then I get

```
The text "Abmelden" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ResponseTextException)
```

This is very frustrating since I actually should be seeing "Abmelden"...

I have tried this with multiple versions and configurations of behat / mink. I have also tried looking for other text content on the user dashboard. But it seems I am missing a very fundamental piece of information here.

**Edit:**

I have dumped the page after I let the routine click on `"Anmelden"`. What I get is the following xdebug dump:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Shopware\Components\CSRFTokenValidationException: The provided X-CSRF-Token for path "/s5224/account/login/sTarget/account/sTargetAction/index" is invalid. Please go back, reload the page and try again. in /home/vagrant/www/s5224/engine/Shopware/Components/CSRFTokenValidator.php on line
```

I assumed that the `goutte` driver just cannot handle this kind of behaviour so annotated the scenario with `@javascript`.

The scenario now looks like:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Test Basic Login
  Given I am on "/account"
  And I login successfully as "demo@demo.de" with password "demodemo"
  Then I should see "Abmelden"
```

That now gave me the option to use something like (as suggested by lauda here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207434/2815176)

```
$this->getSession()->wait(10000, "document.readyState === 'complete'");
```

Interestingly though, the scenario now no longer seems to be able to get on the `account` page. When I dump the page it is completely empty. Even when I wait for up to 60 seconds.

So now the problem seems to be either to get the `selenium2` driver to actually access the `account` page, or to get the `goutte` driver to handle the `X-CSRF-Token` problem.

Comment: Make sure you wait for the page to be loaded, add a small wait for debugging or a breakpoint, and if you see it but the step still fails then maybe is case sensitive somehow, inspect the page and copy the text from there.

Comment: @lauda I have tried all that. I have been waiting for up to 2 mins. I realized that after a Login there is actually a redirect happening. I thought that might be the source of the problem, but all I could find online was instructions on how to **avoid** redirecting. so it seems to me that following the redirect is in fact the default behaviour, which is exactly what I want. It is still not working. I have tried many different texts I have copied directly from the user dashboard.

Comment: Have you tried a wait for the page to be loaded like here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200240/behat-selenium-2-wait-for-page-to-load

Comment: @lauda I have edited the original question, maybe those errors are something you have encountered before?

Comment: @lauda pls look at the edit. I know we are dealing in milliseconds. I dumped the page and found an x-debug error concerning csrf tokens. how would I solve that problem?